# when parent addclass css animation works but when remove they still do nothing?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

```js
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
  if( window.pageYOffset > 0 ) {
    $("body").addClass("scroll");
  }else{
    $("body").removeClass("scroll");
  }
})
```

```css
@keyframes fade {
  0%,100% { opacity: 1 }
  30%,70% { opacity: 0 }
}

.logo{
  animation: fade 0.7s linear;
}

div{
  height: 1000px;
}
span{
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
}
body.scroll span{
  animation: fade 0.7s linear;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,100% { opacity: 1 }
  30%,70% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>test<span>hier</span></div>
```

see that "hier" fade out and in again, but if you scroll to top they stand still. I want if scroll already to top the animation again. ever if body becomes the class scroll and if they remove.

how can i do this only in css?

[**codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwjQeZ)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: i think i misunderstood your question, sorry about that! So you want the span to fade while scrolling down AND up? but only once?

---

the problem lies in your fade animation keyframe, try:

```
 @keyframes fade {
   0% { opacity: 1 }
   100%{ opacity: 0 }
  }
```

I also added the scroll class to the span (you shouldn't add it to the body tag) , and added a small transition to the span, so that the reappearing doesn't seem so abrupt. and if you see in the commented part, i added a "forwards" so that your animation stops at the last "image".

```
span{
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: opacity .4s linear;
}
span.scroll{
  animation: fade 0.7s linear forwards;  // <---- HERE
}
```

Comment: no sorry, i want if i scroll down one fade out and fade in than you can more scrolling and so on but if you scroll to top again (pageOffsetY=0) the span must fade out and fade in again. this is an example, in my testarea there is more meaningful :) but the class must added to body

Comment: well, did you try the code i wrote? 
just change it back to `body.scroll span` and it should work

Comment: and of course use your original keyframes. 
here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgyqZx) you might want to consider to do the check against the pageOffSet a little higher, so that the class get's removed even if the user didn't scroll _entirely_ to the top ( 0 )

Comment: thank you, i try the code but if i scroll from bottom to top theres no animation!? i dont what to hide the span! they must fadeout and immediately fadein if offsetY > 0 and when i reach the top offsetY = 0 but only with css. i hope you can understand my english

Comment: ah sorry, i misunderstood you again. you're german, right? maybe you could just say shortly what you want in german :D